# How to prevent break of NFS connection?

Tags: server, mount, permissions, nfs

First of all I am new in this forum and not a native English speaker. Out of this any help and patience would be appreciated ;-)

I have an Ubuntu server and a Linux Mint client.

For Backup reasons I provided on my client a NFS Export for my server. With this the server can do a second backup on my client.

As long as I logged in to the client, the access from the server to my client and the backup works fine.

After I log out my user from the client, the server gets a permission denied while trying to do a backup. (client is still running)

Content of `/etc/exports` on client:

```
/export/Backup2 server(rw,sync,crossmnt,no_root_squash)
```

Content of `/etc/fstab` on client:

```
/dev/sdb1 /home/locuser/Backup2 ext4    defaults        0       0 
/home/locuser/Backup2/srv_backup      /export/Backup2 none    bind    0       0
```

Content of `/etc/fstab` on server:

```
client:/export/Backup2       /home/Backup2   nfs4    defaults,rw     0       0
```

The output of `ls -la` on the server:

```
....
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root    4096 Feb 22 19:54 Backup 
d?????????  ? ?    ?          ?            ? Backup2 
....
```

I assumed that the shares are still available after logout. It seems, that I am wrong. How can I keep the shares available after logout, or what did I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution myself and I want to share it with you:

In the past, I entered my known hosts only in the `/etc/hosts` file.
After entering the same into `/etc/hosts.allow` file everything works fine.

Comment: Please don't put SOLVED in the title. Mark your answer as the correct one instead.

Comment: I would have suspected an encrypted home directory